# on :hover trigger another element on same hierarchy depth

Tags: css

In a case I'm unable to alter the hierarchy of DOM-element. I'm facing a situation where I have a button, based on 3 spans (button-left, button-content, button-right).

```
<span class="button-left"></span>
<span class="button-content">My button</span>
<span class="button-right"></span>
```

When `.button-content:hover` is activated I'd also like to activate `.button-left:hover` and `.button-right:hover`. Can this be done purely by CSS? I know it can be done using jQuery, but I'm looking for a CSS-only solution in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done if all element is after your hover element via pure css like this

```
.button-content:hover, .button-content:hover + .button-right{background: red;}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uAK5M/)

But we can't select the previous element with css.

If you can wrap all your span with a div, it could be easy like this

```
div:hover > span{background: red;}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uAK5M/1/)

Comment: I figured that out as well. Thanks for mentioning siblings. Haven't heard of them before.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at css sibling.

```
.button-content {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.button-right {
    background-color: grey;
}
.button-content:hover {
    background-color: blue;    
}

.button-right:hover, .button-content:hover+.button-right {
    background-color: pink;    
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nyzm/baWky/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you target the parent link hover action and do something based on that?

```
<a class="button">
    <span class="button-left">one</span>
    <span class="button-content">My button</span>
    <span class="button-right">three</span>
</a>

a.button:hover .button-left    { background-color: red; }
a.button:hover .button-content { background-color: red; }
a.button:hover .button-right   { background-color: red; }
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xp5e8/

Comment: Unfortunately I can't alter the structure, and for the purpose it's not desired to manipulate the DOM on the fly.

Comment: I don't think you need to alter the DOM - the spans must sit inside something (presumably a link tag)? I'm suggesting that you look at the parent tag and simply target the hover on that instead (but I'm assuming that it has a consistent class or an id associated with it).